# Cannot fetch OAuth Token in Logic App because of grant_type issues

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to fetch the OAuth Access token in Logic App using the HTTP request task. But I couldn't fetch token and I am facing the error. The Client Id and Client Secrets were valid and working fine from postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to change the request body. This page answered my question https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d54c668f-d8e3-4662-b124-d9abc3176c8c/http-post-body-parameters-to-get-oauth2-token?forum=azurelogicapps

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution [as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)